# Django form.save step by step

Tags: python, django, super

Let's say I have a form for adding/editing products (with field 'user' being a foreign key to my User) triggered from two separate view functions - add/edit :

```
def product_add(request):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(user=request.user)
    else:
        form = ProductAddForm()
    return render_to_response('products/product_add.html', {
            'form':form, 'user':request.user,
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def product_edit(request, id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, user=request.user)
    if product.user.id!=request.user.id:
        raise Http404
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductAddForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(user=request.user)            
    else:
        form = ProductAddForm(instance=product)
    return render_to_response('products/product_edit.html', {
            'form':form, 'user':request.user,
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The form's save method looks as follows :

```
def save(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.instance.user = user                           
    post = super(ProductAddForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    post.save()
```

Can somebody tell me what's happening in this save method step by step ?Why do we call super on this form and what is the difference in whole processing when we edit and save new product if function call is the same ?

Comment: Have you looked at docs.python.org to see what the `super` function does? http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super  What did you learn there?

Comment: What do you mean by "editing"?  Do you mean "validating"?  That's a separate feature of a Form.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: By "2 views" do you mean "two view functions"?  If so, please UPDATE your question with all this information.  Please STOP adding comments.  Please UPDATE the question to contain ALL the facts.  Then delete the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> self.instance.user = user

Save the user argument into the self.instance object's user attribute

> post = super(ProductAddForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Invoke the superclass save method to get a resulting object.

> post.save()

Save the resulting object.  This may be needless, or it may be essential, depending on the arguments to `save`.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method.  If commit is False, then the `post` object has not been saved to the database.